# Smart contract method relayer

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I was wondering if there was a way, in theory, to call from a sc two functions from a secondary sc in which the result from the first function is a parameter of the second function so something like:

```
Contract 1

function one(uint a, unit b) public returns(uint){
    uint c = a+b 
    return c
}

function two(uint c, uint d)public returns(uint){
    uint d = c+d
    return d
}
```

and

```
Contract 2

function combine(){
     one(a + b)
     two(c + d)
}
```

Clarifications:

I cannot combine them.

The second requires the first to be executed.

I cannot extrapolate the result of the first in any way

It has to be executed within the second contract.

Comment: you mean the out put of the first function to be used as a parameter of second? can you return some value which you can assign as variable and then use it?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. Assuming that these two contracts are deployed indipendently:

First, deploy the first contract:

```
contract first{

    function one(uint256 a, uint256 b) public pure returns(uint){
        uint256 c = a + b; 
        return c;
    }

    function two(uint c, uint d)public pure returns(uint){
        uint256 e = c + d;
        return e;
    }

}
```

using the deployment address fo the first contract, build the second contract like this:

```
contract second{

    first firstContract = first('put here the first contract address');

    function combine(uint256 a, uint256 b, uint256 d) public view returns(uint256){
         uint256 c = firstContract.one(a, b);
         uint256 e = firstContract.two(c, d);
         return e;
    }

}
```

That will work. Test it on Remix.

Hope this helps.